# How to plot a series of arrows from a list of vectors?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics, visualization, vector

Suppose I had a list of 3-vectors as a time series like the following:

```
time = {0., 30., 60., 90., 120., 150., 180., 210., 240., 270., 300., 330., 360., 390., 420., 450., 480., 510., 540., 570.}
vecs = {{2.93179, -0.398459, 2.08849}, {2.795, -0.251351, 2.27032}, {2.63001, -0.219471, 2.44418}, {2.60393, 0.179043, 2.5058}, {2.92059, -0.600426, 2.07901}, {2.75591, 0.143308, 2.4529}, {2.71619, 0.345656, 2.45658}, {2.78439, -0.065008, 2.44869}, {2.71651, 0.23669, 2.53519}, {2.75258, -0.177952, 2.52591}, {2.70081, -0.316687, 2.55583}, {2.59737, 0.613201, 2.58936}, {2.46185, 0.675756, 2.62999}, {2.5193, 0.61026, 2.65494}, {2.58131, 0.586542, 2.63017}, {2.4906, 0.649325, 2.65685}, {2.57245, 0.490279, 2.64862}, {2.64467, 0.421626, 2.54519}, {2.75493, 0.118675, 2.51702}, {2.70534, -0.404308, 2.5537}};
```

I want to be able to plot these in a user-specified plane of projection (e.g., XY) as a series of arrows (e.g., `Arrow[]`).  I have tried a dozen or so different approaches but the issue is that all the outputs look like a flat arrow with no height due to scaling and normalization.  I want the output to look like a bunch of arrows sticking out of a time line in the plane chosen by the user, where the i<sup>th</sup> tail starts at `{time[[i]],0}`.  I am guessing my issues have been with improper scaling but I am also running into confusion about mapping/distributing the `Arrow` operator/function over a list of 3-vectors (I created a list of two-components from each 3-vector but am getting stuck on application).

I am looking to generate something like the following image but the arrows stay on a horizontal line and the user gets to specify the arrow density and the plane of projection from a right-handed, orthonormal basis like cartesian coordinates.

[image: arrows on line]

The idea is that I can give the function an arbitrary number of 3-vectors and associated time stamps and it will generate an auto-scaled plot in the user-specified plane with the user-specified density of (or total number of) arrows.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the plot related to the 3d-vectors time-series data you showed? What is on the x-axis and the y-axis and what is the black curve? If possible show the code you have used to generate this projection so people can better understand the problem.

Comment: Time is on the horizontal axis defining where the tails start, the horizontal and vertical extent of each arrow is defined by the 2D projection onto a user-specified plane (e.g., XY).  The whole point is to see how a vector field evolves in time from a single-point measurement through some region.  The example image is only to illustrate the displacement of the tail of each arrow away from the origin and that each can have any arbitrary pointing direction (though I think this example is showing a gradient so it's not arbitrary).

Comment: So is your problem a math or Mathematica issue? are you able to get the `projectedVectors` for any plane say for example $z=x+y$ or $z=0$ (XY-plane)? If yes then plotting them as a sequence of arrows horizontally aligned is not difficult.

Comment: Note if your projection is on a plane other than $x=0$ (YZ-plane), $y=0$ (XZ-plane) or $z=0$ (XY-plane) then the projected vector will need three coordinates. In that case, you need to redefine/transform coordinates so you have one of them zero to again be able to plot them on a 2D graph.

Comment: @user13892 - In the case I am specifically interested in, it's the magnetic field measured by a spacecraft in the solar wind.  It is a vector field, it's just varying in time and space due to variations in the sources.  The planes of projection are, yes, at the origin of the third component so we only need to scale the other 2 components.  This problem is trivial mathematically, it's more an issue to get Mathematica to behave for me.